# how to log reboots dates

Tags: linux, raspbian, reboot

I'm new to Linux, and I'm always unsecure if I'm doing things the proper way
I'm using a Raspbian system that sometimes reboots ( for some non software problems ) and I want to have a log on when each reboots happens.
My idea was this: crontab task like:

```
@reboot date >> /var/log/reboots
```

and it works.
Is there something more elegant? If the solution is acceptable, is there some way to "roll" the log file to avoid filling the file system of dates ;) ?

Comment: Check `last reboot`.

Comment: sounds better, but on my system I can just have last two days, I suppose because the standard log file rolled out. Any more sugegstion to control how far int the past last reboot can see?

Comment: Depending on your distro: `last reboot -f /var/log/wtmp.1` (or `.2`, `.3`...).

Comment: @muru ty feel free to answer, I will acept it with pleasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Debian, reboots are logged. From [`man last`](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?&query=last):

```
Last searches back through the file /var/log/wtmp (or the  file  desig-
nated  by  the -f flag) and displays a list of all users logged in (and
out) since that file was created.
...
The pseudo user reboot logs in each time the system is rebooted.   Thus
last  reboot will show a log of all reboots since the log file was cre-
ated.
```

The `/var/log/wtmp` file should already be under log rotation by default (see `/etc/logrotate.conf`), taking care of that.

You can use older log files using the `-f` option:

```
last reboot -f /var/log/wtmp.1
```

Answer (score 1):

A crontab entry is ok, but requires for `cron` to be started. I myself would tend to put something like that line into `/etc/rc.local` which is invoked at the end of reaching the multi-user runlevel.

Both might not be invoked if you start (willingly or not) in single-user mode. If that is not accurate enough, you might want to look at taking a different path and analysing `/var/log/syslog` for recent bootmessages and add all date-time-stamps to a file after the last one you recorded in such way. You can run this from `cron` or `rc.local`, but it assumes that `/var/log/syslog` gets properly preserved between reboots.

I would not worry about this single 30 character write on reboot, that is not going to fill your disc more than anything else. If you really think that is a problem, then just record the same using 4 bytes (32 bits) as binary in a file. You could further reduce this by diminishing the accuracy and then store some delta between reboots.

Comment: Disk in raspbian is an SD, this is the reson in being worried about space consuption

Comment: @FelicePollano But SD cards come in GB sizes mostly nowadays. I needed an  8GB SD for the bananapi I set up. Even using ASCII at 30 characters, you can roughly record 32K reboots in 1Mb. At 20 seconds per reboot that would still only consume 1Mb in a week when constantly rebooting.

Comment: yeah, you are probably right